# Renderings xml seems to be suddenly broken

Tags: presentation

We encountered something strange with the renderings.
We have a form with 4 steps. All the 4 steps have the same template, but they all have different renderings. For steps 1 to 3, the renderings are loaded correctly (even in the CM the renderings are visible in the correct order in the presentation details). But for step 4 We get that not Layout was specified and no renderings are specified. Now the strange part starts, if we enable the "raw values" we get the following XMLs:

**Step 1 to 3 (working perfectly):**

```XML
<r xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
    <d id="{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}" l="{6D2049B2-34CE-4653-BEC9-206860EB9857}">
        <r id="{CA8A09FA-6353-4CBF-94DB-92CD68D163B0}" ph="local-belgium-main" uid="{FD256D71-16B6-449E-8C08-42BFE2A6CD4B}" />
        <r ds="" id="{BC464D77-8FB4-410C-A46D-8F2171DF18C7}" par="" ph="local-belgium-constrained" uid="{8C90ABF4-FFAA-4050-B099-F71C8D61C15C}" />
        <r ds="{39ECF3E9-B19B-41A7-8A6F-59F0DBDB728E}" id="{966998AF-44C5-4FF4-A3BA-DDEC8DE7076C}" par="" ph="local-belgium-constrained" uid="{BACB3C74-CFF4-4495-91F4-E12043B04D58}" />
        <r ds="" id="{E095D3B6-E620-450D-A225-961BE12283EF}" par="" ph="local-belgium-constrained" uid="{A1FFA733-32C9-480F-BE2E-38352D99E0B9}" />
        <r id="{5A0E0EFE-21D4-4194-A772-90E88085B7AA}" ph="local-belgium-constrained" uid="{BC2CCD71-A242-463D-8231-9C75A90EC61E}" />
        <r ds="{82E0C067-87BD-47C8-B419-E0D66923C2A8}" id="{55CBED47-26DF-4AEE-9FBA-82A5ADB5B9AD}" par="" ph="local-belgium-left" uid="{FBFFDFFB-B753-47DA-829A-C284B9AAF49C}" />
        <r ds="{1CA34AA9-905A-492A-AAAD-291C2546BEE1}" id="{A62834D4-B607-42D5-9F90-FEFB715006B1}" par="" ph="local-belgium-left" uid="{CE158AFF-9B73-4A41-95D9-46A48E0125DD}" />
    </d>
</r>
```

**Step 4 (NOT WORKING):**

```
<r  xmlns:p="p" xmlns:s="s" p:p="1">
    <d id="{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}">
        <r uid="{A676EFBC-370E-46B7-B5F9-94D47D9093AC}">
            <p:d />
        </r><r uid="{4DA8179B-5CCC-4114-A322-F1C8AB41D955}">
            <p:d />
        </r><r uid="{FD256D71-16B6-449E-8C08-42BFE2A6CD4B}" p:before="*" s:id="{CA8A09FA-6353-4CBF-94DB-92CD68D163B0}" s:ph="local-belgium-main" />
        <r uid="{8C90ABF4-FFAA-4050-B099-F71C8D61C15C}" p:after="r[@uid='{FD256D71-16B6-449E-8C08-42BFE2A6CD4B}']" s:ds="" s:id="{BC464D77-8FB4-410C-A46D-8F2171DF18C7}" s:par="" s:ph="local-belgium-constrained" />
        <r uid="{A1FFA733-32C9-480F-BE2E-38352D99E0B9}" p:after="r[@uid='{8C90ABF4-FFAA-4050-B099-F71C8D61C15C}']" s:ds="" s:id="{E095D3B6-E620-450D-A225-961BE12283EF}" s:par="" s:ph="local-belgium-constrained" />
        <r uid="{CE158AFF-9B73-4A41-95D9-46A48E0125DD}" p:after="*[1=2]" s:ds="{BAFB7E03-2E60-4677-80BC-CF2CE2D48923}" s:id="{D51D5868-8695-49EE-A63B-9CCBA46633DB}" s:par="" s:ph="local-belgium-constrained" />
    </d>
</r>
```

As you can see, the XML is differently formatted. Is there something we can do to fix this? or do we manually need to adapt the faulty XML?

Answer (score 4):

The values in Steps 1-3 is a straight value...meaning it is NOT a delta value. Therefore you will be getting exactly what the renderings referenced here specify on the item, and NOTHING will come from the Standard Values.

Step 4 IS a delta value (notice the `xmlns:p="p" xmlns:s="s"`, and most of the parameters are preceded with a `s:`.
So for this item, you will get what the Standard Values renderings state, with it modified by this delta value on top.

You will need to check this XML against the raw values of the Standard Values field to see what it's doing.
For example, I can see that it is deleting (`<p:d />`) whatever rendering has `uid="{A676EFBC-370E-46B7-B5F9-94D47D9093AC}"`. Same with `uid="{4DA8179B-5CCC-4114-A322-F1C8AB41D955}"`.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen issues like this where content sync strategies have mangled presentation (or left devices which don't exist within the presentation hidden and difficult to locate).

I would recommend following these steps:
1. Copy the raw presentation to Notepad++ for safekeeping.
2. Reset the item to standard values (assuming resetting the content won't be too much of a pain - [or you might be able to reset individual fields although it's not something I've done](http://firebreaksice.com/how-to-reset-individual-sitecore-fields-to-standard-values/)).

Then take a look at the raw value - if it still looks weird the issue might lie on your __Standard Values on the template. I would advise clearing out the presentation on this field and rebuild it - you should be able to completely empty out the raw value of this field and then rebuild it using the Presentation UI dialog.

If the problem doesn't lie on the template - you can do the same on the content item (clear out the presentation and rebuild it).

Answer (score 0):

What I can see the schema of step 4 is different from that of step 1 to 3. Put the same xmlns.xsd schema to step4 with Id and ds in the same way in the raw value.

Comment: Can you show what the corrected xml would look like, highlight the differences from the original and explaining why your changes are necessary? As it stands, your post identifies the issue, but doesn't provide much to learn from.